# Injecting a CoroutineDispatcher using Koin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, koin

I was reading the [data layer guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide/data-layer?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-architecture%23article-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fjetpack%2Fguide%2Fdata-layer#create_the_data_source) by Google and in the linked segment, they have the following snippet:

```
class NewsRemoteDataSource(
  private val newsApi: NewsApi,
  private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) {
    /**
     * Fetches the latest news from the network and returns the result.
     * This executes on an IO-optimized thread pool, the function is main-safe.
     */
    suspend fun fetchLatestNews(): List<ArticleHeadline> =
        // Move the execution to an IO-optimized thread since the ApiService
        // doesn't support coroutines and makes synchronous requests.
        withContext(ioDispatcher) {
            newsApi.fetchLatestNews()
        }
    }
}

// Makes news-related network synchronous requests.
interface NewsApi {
    fun fetchLatestNews(): List<ArticleHeadline>
}
```

Injecting the NewsApi dependency using Koin is pretty straightforward, but how can I inject a CoroutineDispatcher instance using Koin? I used the search functionality on Koin's website but nothing came up. A filtered ddg search doesn't yield many results either.

Comment: Something like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70331729/differ-coroutines-dispatchers-when-using-koin-as-di-framework#comment124326020_70331729) . this is just a question i can not find an better one right now . read the comments also .

Comment: @ADM Thank you, a link in the comment section of the linked questions helped me out. I'll post a solution using named scopes soon!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to @ADM's link from the comments, I managed to use a named property as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629957/is-it-possible-to-create-different-instances-of-the-same-object-and-access-them/56630047#56630047).

In my case, I first create the named property for the IO Dispatcher, then the SubjectsLocalDataSource class gets its CoroutineDispatcher dependency using the `get(named("IODispatcher"))` call and finally, the SubjectsRepository gets its data source dependency using the classic `get()` call.

SubjectsLocalDataSource declaration:

```
class SubjectsLocalDataSource(
    private val database: AppDatabase,
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
)
```

SubjectsRepository declaration:

```
class SubjectsRepository(private val subjectsLocalDataSource: SubjectsLocalDataSource)
```

and finally, in my Koin module:

```
single(named("IODispatcher")) {
    Dispatchers.IO
}

// Repositories
single { SubjectsRepository(get()) }

// Data sources
single { SubjectsLocalDataSource(get(), get(named("IODispatcher"))) }
```